# xfce4 подвисает при извлечении usb накопителя

Tags: linux, usb, fedora, xfce

Система с проблемой: RFRemix 26, 27 (XFCE4)

Нормально работало: RFRemix 25 (XFCE4)

Описание проблемы: При извлечении ЮЗБ диска (карта СД в картидере) наблюдается такая ошибка. После нажатия на пункт меню "извлечь" меню остается (рабочий стол не перерисовывается) и весь рабочий стол подвисает. Значки не реагируют на нажатия, через некоторое время и вовсе пропадают. После вытаскивания карты через секунд 20 все нормализуется.

Команда umount с консоли работает корректно, устройство извлекается.

Comment: Если важно, могу добавить, что все программы при этом работают без сбоев.

Comment: убей thunar, который работает с рабочим столом и запусти его вручную с консоли. при извлечении флешки посмотри нет ли чего интересного там

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрел логи

```
гру 26 13:30:09 localhost.localdomain plasma_waitforname[3545]: org.kde.knotifications: WaitForName: Service was not registered within timeout
гру 26 13:30:09 localhost.localdomain dbus-daemon[1589]: [session uid=1000 pid=1589] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.Notifications' failed: Process org.freedesktop.Notifications exited with status 1
гру 26 13:30:09 localhost.localdomain dbus-daemon[1589]: [session uid=1000 pid=1589] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.Notifications' requested by ':1.9' (uid=1000 pid=1649 comm="xfdesktop --display :0.0 --sm-client-id 224300dca-"
```

Как оказалось причиной было невозможность показать оповещение на рабочий стол. Окно настроек оповещений подвисало так же при настройке внешнего вида и др. параметров.

Как решение: установить dunst. НО это решило проблему частично: рабочий стол перестал виснуть, флешки извлекаются, но сами оповещения отображаются некорректно (слева вверху на синем фоне)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и не поддаются настройке